Compose Desktop работа с Реестром
Как записать или прочитать ключ реестра в Kotlin Compose Desktop Windows.

Вряд ли это должно поддерживаться из коробки в силу кроссплатформы. Поэтому если кто-то не соорудил либу на эту тему, то делается это прямым вызовом reg.

@vitidev Проверил все работает спасибо.

Для desktop достаточно использовать стандартный Java java.util.Preferences класс, например:
val prefs = Preferences.userRoot()
prefs.put("key", "value")

Они будут записаны в HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
Можно писать и другую ветку: prefs.node("HKEY_CURRENT_USER/<blah-blah>") - только надо следить за пермишенами - не все разрешено.
